# Why is the Event Object different with a click event and with a trigger click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Event Object is different when I do:

```
$('section#top10 ul#periodes li').click(function (e) {
```

and when I do:

```
$('section#top10 ul#periodes li').trigger('click') {
```

I know the trigger function triggers the first function, but the "e" argument is not the same with the two methods. With the first method I can access the srcElement, but with trigger the object attributes are not the same. I would like to know why the two arguments are different when the same function is called.

Comment: Trigger Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Comment: What object attributes exactly?

Comment: Well they are two objects completely different, so pretty much all attributes.

Comment: @Fals But that does not explain why the click handler has a different e argument.

Comment: @Maxwell The reason: Those are two different "click" event variants: One is a natural (user) click, and the other is a programmatic click (triggered from JavaScript alone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when a user clicks on an element, the event carries mouse position like `pageX/pageY` and `clientX/clientY` but using trigger to fire the event programmatically, there will be no real mouse positions because the `click` event fired without the mouse interaction, this is one big difference, at least I can think of. That's why the `e/event` object is different in both cases and it makes sense, IMO.

**Update :**

In other words, it's not a real click event but a simulation of that event and in this case it's a tailored peace, for example, this is the prototype of the `initMouseEvent` ([with example](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtxvfef.php) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent)), which used with `createEvent`

```
object.initMouseEvent (eventName, bubbles, cancelable, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);
```

This used to simulate a mouse event in vanilla `JavaScript` (it may varies in different browsers), also look at [this](http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2011/11/29/programatically-fire-crossbrowser-click-event-with-javascript/), so in case of `jQuery` it's (event object created by `trigger`) a tailored object that `jQuery` build for cross browser support when using `trigger` and it's not same as the one that is in real `click` event, completely two different objects.